# How to read write inside the adb shell using python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am facing issue while reading/writing string from the shell.

```
pros = subprocess.Popen("adb shell /usr/bin/bta",stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
pros.communicate()

the output of this would be 
#bta
a
b
c
exit
```

Now I want to open data contains in a.which is,

```
1
2
3
```

I tried using `peroc.stdin.write(" ")` which is not working until we come out from the shell. Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to understand - you're trying to pipe input into a subprocess, and fetch the results from that subprocess, while the subprocess is still running?

Comment: did you try to use pros.communicate?

Comment: yes but pros.communicate is not working.

Comment: @ Roy2012 The problem is an inside shell the write is not working.  proc.stdin.write is working when we are in shell # .... The App or program which i am using is acquiring shell like #app      then a , b, c